# QSystemTrayIcon.setIcon not working to change the tray icon

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsystemtrayicon

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class autoparse():
    def __init__(self):

       self.main()

    def main(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("icons\icon-windowed.ico"), app)
        self.menu = QMenu()
        self.autopconfig = self.menu.addAction('Config')
        self.autopconfig.triggered.connect(self.swapicon)
        self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.menu)

        self.trayIcon.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    def swapicon(self):
        QSystemTrayIcon.setIcon(QIcon("icons\python.ico"))

test1 = autoparse()
```

I can get the initial icon to set just fine and I can work around the issue by creating 2 icons for app and then doing a self.trayIcon.hide() and self.newicon.show() but I don't feel this is the right way to do it.

Pycharm shows a notice saying "Expected QSystemTrayIcon, got QIcon" but if I swap `QIcon` with `QSystemTrayIcon` then it says `Qicon` is missing. SOOOOOO I change it to `QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("icons\python.ico")` and it still says `QIcon` is unfilled. It seems like the problem detection is going in circles.

Running the code as is gives me "setIcon (self, QIcon): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QSystemTrayIcon'" when I run the swapicon function. If I remove QIcon so its just setIcon (file) then I get "setIcon (self, QIcon): not enough arguments"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QSystemTrayIcon is not a static element so to change some property you must use the instance, in your case you must change:

```
QSystemTrayIcon.setIcon(QIcon("icons\python.ico"))
```

to:

```
self.trayIcon.setIcon(QIcon("icons\python.ico"))
```

You may have been confused with `QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("icons\icon-windowed.ico"), app)`, this is a constructor and can receive the icon.